# App crash when start debug with VS mac

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

App getting crash out with the below error when it start debugging.

> The connection with the debugger has been lost. The target application may have exited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to breakpoints. By clearing all the breakpoints, am able to run the app without crash.